# Facebook Canvas application using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, oauth

Hope someone can help me out. I have a facebook canvas application. I'm using this code to authenticate

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: '123842974364777',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});

        this.vars = {
            access_token: '',
            album_id: '',
            items: '',
            user_id: '',
            photo_path: '',
            errorHandler: 'There was a problem posting your picture!<br> Please contact <a href="mailto:support@eshots.com">support@eshots.com</a>',
            counter: 1
        }

    authenticate();

    function authenticate() {

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if(response.authResponse) {
                // logged and known to app
                // store access token
                vars.access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                sendUserInformation();
            } else {
                // not logged in or unknow to app
                // prompt user to authorize app
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if(response.authResponse) {
                        // store access token
                        vars.access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken
                        sendUserInformation();
                    }
                }, {scope: 'email,read_stream,user_birthday,user_photos,publish_stream'});          
            }
        });
    } 

};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol
        + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

My problem is, running this code doesn't show my page in a facebook iframe. it just stays on the web domain. What I need is to get this page shown in a facebook iframe.

What do I have to add to make this happen?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your canvas url/secure url in the developer app to point to your canvas code?

This should essentially point to your domain like http://mydomain.com/mycanvasfolder where the canvas folder would have the index page you want to show.

You should be able to see a basic page without any other configuration or FB stuff.

Comment: Hi Dustin! Yes, that is all set!

Comment: If you access the link you configured for the facebook settings directly do you get a response?   The code you're using should work through the iframe or when accessed directly through your website.